# $post is null while in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

According to WP documentation this can't be happening but it is:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

> You can display other information about each post using the
>   appropriate Template Tags or (for advanced users) by accessing the
>   $post variable, which is set with the current post's information while
>   The Loop is running.

All following code examples use $post to access the current post but I can't. Even though it goes in the loop $post is null:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'carousel_bootstrap', 'posts_per_page' => 10);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    var_dump($post->ID);//=NULL
    $title=the_title(null,null,false);
    var_dump($title);//string(4) "NOPE"
....
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

So either $post should not be null or the var_dump should not execute in the loop. I need to access this current post's custom fields but can't do it if $post is null. To make it more confusing; in the next line the $title variable is set to the current post's title.

How would I go about solving this? Using word press 3.6.1

**[UPDATE]**

I made a custom post called carousel, thought I'd use it to contain the html code for a twitter bootstrap carousel. In header I'm calling a function that checks if a custom carousel post exist with a certain name (provided by a custom value from the page).

In the header $post is the page, in the function checking the custom post the $post is null and when exiting the function and continuing in the header $post is the custom post (no longer the page).

Seemed like a good idea to do it this way when I started but looks like it can't be done this way.

Comment: Have you tried checking the output of `var_dump($post)`?

Comment: @koala_dev Thank you for your help. I sort of had nested `the loops` added an answer to this. From page.php I called a function in functions.php that loops over custom posts, not sure what I did wrong but WP didn't like it and had some unexpected results. It's kind of working now although it can use some improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it doing what it does but think the code could use some improvement:

(added on blankslate)

In /wp-content/themes/blankslate/functions.php

```
//only using single carousel per page now
$vars=array('carouselHtml'=>'<div style="h'.
  'eight:100px"><h1>Working, no Carousel</h1></div>',
    'css'=>[],
    'js'=>[]
);
function getInits(){
  global $vars;
  return $vars;
}
function setInits() {
  global $post;
  global $vars;
  //see if the page specified a carousel (if value it's the title)
  $carousel = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'carousel', true);
  //collect all custom fields named "js" usually to fix screen
  //re sizing like hiding images or big sliders
  $scriptItems = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'js', false);
  if ($scriptItems) {
    foreach ($scriptItems as $item) {
      $vars["js"][]=$item;
    }
  }
  //load all custom fields of the page named css
  //can be used for specific styles for the page
  $cssItems = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'css', false);
  if ($cssItems) {
    foreach ($cssItems as $item) {
      $vars["css"][]=$item;
    }
  }
  //page has a custom field value named carousel
  //it contains the title of the custom post that
  //should contain the html, css and js
  if ($carousel) {
    //nice and intuitive query, gotta love it
    $args = array('post_type' => 
      'carousel_bootstrap',
      'title' => $carousel,
      'posts_per_page' => 100);
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
      $title=the_title(null,null,false);
      if($title===$carousel){
        //found the custom carousel post, load html
        //and add css js not to the page because css
        //goes in the top and js goes in the bottom
        $tmp=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'js', true);
        if($tmp){$vars["js"][]=$tmp;}
        $tmp=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'css', true);
        if($tmp){$vars["css"][]=$tmp;}
        $vars["carouselHtml"]=$post->post_content;
        break;
      }
    endwhile;
    //$post was the page at the start of the function
    //now it could be the carousel post, not sure
    //if the following is needed but works either
    //with or without it
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
}

//creating custom post named carousel
add_action('init', 'create_carousel_post_type');
function create_carousel_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'carousel_bootstrap', array(
      'labels' => array(
          'name' => __('Carousels'),
          'singular_name' => __('Carousel')
      ),
      'public' => false,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'carousels'),
      'show_ui' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','author',
        'thumbnail','custom-fields','revisions')
  ));
}
```

In /wp-content/themes/blankslate/page.php

```
setInits();
get_header(); 
....
<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="top">

<!-- Carousel
    based on http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php 
$vars=getInits();
echo $vars["carouselHtml"];
?>
```

In /wp-content/themes/blankslate/header.php

```
$vars=getInits();
//output collected css
foreach ($vars["css"] as $item) {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$item.'" />';
}
```

The footer has same sort of code but for JavaScripts.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to get the post id in a custom WP_QUERY is: `$loop->post->ID`

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'carousel_bootstrap', 'posts_per_page' => 10); 

$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
global $post;

while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

       $loop->post->ID; //This is how you get the id $post will not work unless you
       setup_postdata( $loop->post->ID );
       print_r($post->ID); //now works. 

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'carousel_bootstrap', 'posts_per_page' => 10);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()): while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
   //echo the title
   the_title();
   the_content();
   //get the ID
   $postId = get_the_ID();
endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Just a note: Isn't the `if` statement redundant (i.e. already covered by `while`)?

Comment: Useful when you want to show something when there are no posts (in an `ELSE` statement)

Comment: True, although there's no indication that's the case here... Anyway.

Comment: I don't want to dump the content, as explained in my update; made a custom post and want to use that to hold the html code of twitter bootstrap slider(s). In the page I'll set a custom field with the slider name that should be the title of the custom post. In the custom post there are custom fields like css (url with css to load), js (urls with js to load). I made 2 mistakes. 1 didn't import the global variable in the function body (PHP rooky). 2. Didn't use `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end of my loop as indicated that you should in nested loops (although it works without it). Will post code

Comment: @HMR thanks for the comment, exactly what I needed "forgot to import global $post;" -- my code was working for archive templates but not category templates, I guess in one place I didn't need to declare global, in other I did... but didn't hurt to declare in both places, so now same code works everywhere.  Rookie mistake, indeed.